# Paypal IPN simulator now wipes out all values after every "Send IPN"

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

As a result of the upgrade of the PayPal developer site, the behavior of the IPN simulator has now taken a huge change for the worse.

Before, you could fill out the form once, and hit "Send IPN" as many times as needed to debug the backend.  Now every time you click "Send IPN", all the data you entered gets reset to the default values.  This means for a form which has 30+ fields, you have to fill it out over and over again every time you want to send the test IPN.

It's bad enough there's no way to save the information indefinitely, but clearing out every field every time you click "Send IPN" is just horrible.

Is there any way to get it to preserve the existing field data?

Comment: yikes - reported it to our dev team. Let me see how soon we can get it fixed. Sorry about that.